# Java listIterator - how do I get it to only iterate once?

Tags: java, loops, iterator, switch-statement

I've written some code that's supposed to simulate a "playlist" of "songs". The "playlist" is represented by a linkedList that should be able the user to sequentially move forwards or backwards through the list. I use a switch statement to allow the user to navigate the playlist. The problem is that if the user selects the option to move to the next song, the program iterates through the entire playlist and then gets stuck printing the "you've reached the end of the list" statement. The break statements in my switch statement are ignored. How do I get the linkedList to only iterate once each time the user selects this option?

```
     public static void playSongs(LinkedList playList){
        boolean quit = false;
        int userInput;
        boolean forward = true; //track direction of movement through the linkedList
        ListIterator<Song> listIterator = playList.listIterator(); //iterate through the linkedList
        if(playList.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("No songs in playlist");
            return;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Now Playing " + listIterator.next().getTitle());
            printMenu();
        }
        userInput = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        while(!quit){
            switch(userInput){
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Exiting playlist");
                    quit = true;
                    break;
/*problem area: if case 1 is selected, the list iterator should print the title of the next song in the list and then break, instead it ignores the "break" statement and prints the title of every remaining song, then keeps printing "you've reached the end of the list."*/
                case 1: 
                    if(!forward){
                        if (listIterator.hasNext()){
                            listIterator.next();
                        }
                        forward = true;
                    }
                    if(listIterator.hasNext()){
                        System.out.println("Now Playing " + listIterator.next().getTitle());
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Reached end of playlist");
                        forward = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if(forward) {
                        if (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                            listIterator.hasPrevious();
                        }
                        forward = false;
                    }
                    if(listIterator.hasPrevious()){
                        System.out.println("Now playing: " + listIterator.previous().getTitle());
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Already at beginning of playlist");
                        forward = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if(forward){
                    if(listIterator.hasPrevious()){
                        System.out.println("Now replaying " + listIterator.previous().getTitle());
                        forward = false;
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Replaying first song");
                    }
                }else{
                    if(listIterator.hasNext()){
                        System.out.println("Now replaying " + listIterator.next().getTitle());
                        forward = true;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Replaying last song in list");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move:

```
    userInput = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
```

inside your while loop:

```
    while(!quit){
        userInput = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
```

without that it just re-processes the initial '1' that the user selected, over and over.